# Append an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, append

I am trying to append an array of dictionaries with latitude and longitude.

This is because I want to add annotations to a map, But I am getting the data from Firebase and need to store them in an array.

I get them from an array of postcode and put them into a dictionary, this all prints fine but now I am trying to add them to a new array.

I want to create an array of dictionaries only. With the final result in posts. i.e `[["latitude: 873648264, "longitude": 9849823658293753], [latitude: 873648264, "longitude": 9849823658293753 ]]`

Below is my code so far, I have looked around for answers and there are so many but I cannot make head nor tale of it.

```
var posts = [[Dictionary<String,Double>]]()

var latitude = Dictionary<String,Double>()
var longitude = Dictionary<String,Double>()
latitude = ["latitude":lat!]
longitude = ["longitude":lon!]
var latLon = ["latitude":latitude, "longitude":longitude]

posts.append(latLon)
```

//Updated question from here:

What aim trying to achieve is to replace this code with the lat and lon of my own data from firebase.

```
let locations = [
["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]

for location in locations {
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is going wrong and what you are expecting as an outcome?

Comment: You should also include in the question in what form you get the data from and for what do you need it, since storing a single long-lat value pair in a dictionary seems overly complicated to me.

Comment: I have now updated the question to show what I am trying to do, Thank you for the help on this.

Comment: Man, I hate to say this but that code is really bad. Storing everything in dictionaries is a great way to make mistakes. Instead you should create a custom `class`/`struct` and store those in the array, this should help you prevent mistakes or catch them more easily.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @EmillioPelaez, don't be afraid to tell me its bad its how I will learn I have only been learning a 10 months or so so appreciate all the advice you guys can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array of dictionaries only, this should suffice

```
var posts = [[String: Double]]()

var latLon = ["latitude":lat!, "longitude": lon!]

posts.append(latLon)
```

Comment: I want to create an array of dictionaries only. With the final result in posts. i.e [["latitude: 873648264, "longitude": 9849823658293753], [latitude: 873648264, "longitude": 9849823658293753 ]]

Comment: Edited for what you want instead

Comment: Thank you for this help @pruthvikar. This worked perfect once you was able to grasp what i wanted to achieve. Sorry it was vague at first, I will try to make them better in the future.